# Webpack-RequireJS interop hacking: Module has not been loaded in context error, but sibling has

Tags: webpack, requirejs

I have a problem in a system where we liberally mix and match Webpack and RequireJS. We have a static code base creating a Web UI of sorts, but within this Web UI dynamic parts can be requested from other places.

The static Web UI part is built using Webpack. The dynamic parts, however, are naturally requested using RequireJS. Now this is nice and simple, but the problem comes that some of those dynamic parts want to refer back to the static part. This would normally cause duplication as RequireJS fetches and initializes the code anew, disregarding the fact that the code is already present in the Webpack-created bundle.

To solve this problem I came up with a (*ingenious*) freaky hack where at the beginning of our static code we import those static parts we know will be required through RequireJS and `window.define("static/code/location", () => import "static/code/location")` (paraphrasing, this actual code would not work of course).

So we essentially grab the Webpack module reference and define to RequireJS that this module provides a particular named module. This actually worked and I was overjoyed.

However a weird problem has appeared. One dynamically required piece of code has, inside it, RequireJS's `const a = require("some/path/a");` syntax and for some reason this particular "some/path/a" errors with `module has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`. This will happen even if, right before the require line, I manually (through developer console) do `define("path/to/a", () => {})`. Furthermore, doing `const b = require("some/path/b");` does work, returns the proper module and doesn't error, despite the path to the modules being the same and both of these modules originally being defined to RequireJS side by side in the freaky hack solution that I described above.

Any clues as to what is happening, why is one of the siblings defined while the other isn't and cannot be defined, would be most appreciated. Although this is definitely not a particularly "good" use case... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix the situation. I still have no idea what actually caused the error, but the way around this was to define `path/to/a` as plain object instead of a parameterless function returning the plain object.

`window.define("path/to/a", import("a"))` (Once again paraphrasing.)